# Sptring Batch: Handle exception during initializing spring boot context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Is there any way to handle exception during initialization of spring boot context?

My case is to handle error during execution of the job and do some work depending on occured exception.

For example, I have a job that consists of reader and writer. Reader and writer are initialized with properties: rootFolder, inFolder, outFolder. This simple job reads file from /rootFolder/inFolder/test.txt and writes data to rootFolder/outFolder/test.txt.

I set the JobExecutionListener to be invoked after job completion and analyse error if job failed.

But if the properties are wrong, the exception(InvalidPathException or NullPointerException) occurs before the job starts (hence the listener won't be called). And I can't analyze the error.

Is any way to add general listener for intercepting and analyzing errors?

Code example configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {

   @Autowired
   public JobConfiguration(JobSpecificProperties properties) {
       this.properties = properties;
   }

   private final JobSpecificProperties properties;

   @Bean
   public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step step) {
       return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobName")
               .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
               .listener(new SystemExitOnFailureJobExecutionListener())
               .start(step)
               .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                 ItemReader<String> itemReader,
                 ItemWriter<String> itemWriter) {
       return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepName")
               .<String, String>chunk(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
               .reader(itemReader)
               .writer(itemWriter)
               .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public ItemReader<String> itemReader() {
       FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
       reader.setStrict(false);
       reader.setLineMapper((string, index) -> string);
       reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(Paths.get(properties.getRootFolder(), properties.getInFolder()).resolve("test.txt").toString()));

       return reader;
   }

   @Bean
   public ItemWriter<String> itemWriter() {
       FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
       writer.setLineAggregator(string -> string);
       writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(Paths.get(properties.getRootFolder(), properties.getOutFolder()).resolve("test.txt").toString()));

       return writer;
   }
}
```

Code example listener class:

```
@Slf4j
public class SystemExitOnFailureJobExecutionListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {
    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED) {
            if (jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions().get(0) instanceof NullPointerException){
                log.error("some_message_1");
                //TODO: Do something
                System.exit(2);
            } else if (jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions().get(0) instanceof InvalidPathException){
                log.error("some_message_2");
                //TODO: Do something
                System.exit(3);
            }

            //TODO: Do something by default
            System.exit(1);
        }
   }
}
```

Code example properties class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties("job.parameter")
public class JobSpecificProperties {
    private String rootFolder;
    private String outFolder;
    private String inFolder;
}
```

Main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JobSpecificProperties.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post main application class?

Comment: @luboskrnac, I have edited my post.

Comment: is try/catch around SpringApplication.run enough for you?

Comment: @NghiaDo, thanks. This is very good idea, but not enough for me. Because i want to know what exactly occurred. For example, in batch job i can validate my properties class in tasklet, and throw specific exception WrongOutFolderParameterException, WrongRootFolderParameterEsception or any exceptions i want. In listener I can analize exception from context. In try/catch block i get a general exception with specific message and i don`t want parse this message for decide what to do.

Comment: @NghiaDo, Conclusion,  i want to validate my properties class or check environment values for existence before batch job starts and throw specific exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to extend class AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy use this class in Job/Step level.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldSkip(java.lang.Throwable t, int skipCount){
     if(t instanceof NonSkippableReadException){
                return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

For more information on handling part go through

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html

```
public interface SkipListener<T,S> extends StepListener {

    void onSkipInRead(Throwable t);
    void onSkipInProcess(T item, Throwable t);
    void onSkipInWrite(S item, Throwable t);

}
```

or create method and annotate them with corresponding annotations:

@OnSkipInRead

@OnSkipInWrite

@OnSkipInProcess

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i need to validate my properties class or check environment values for existence before job start and throw specific exception.